# Best beer styles for warm fermentation environment?

Tags: fermentation, fermentation-temperature, beer-styles

What beer styles tend to work well with a warm (at least 70°F/21°C, possibly up to 90°F/32°C) fermentation environment? In other words, what styles will be best to mask or work with the off-flavors produced?

Comment: This question is similar. http://brewadvice.com/questions/1022/what-beers-are-good-for-summer-brewing

Answer (score 8):

For most people brewing a Saison is a great summer compatible beer to brew.
The saison yeast works best at 80F (or 27C).  And the flavor of saison is often citrusy and light.
You can brew a saison to a variety of OGs for different levels of enjoyment.  You can make a session style saison or a bigger version to pair well with food.

Check out this BJCP link to [Saison](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style16.php#1c).

Comment: Saison is definitely best for hot climates.  Check out Wyeast's Belgian Saison yeast, with ideal fermentation temps of 70 - 95 degrees:  http://www.wyeastlab.com/rw_yeaststrain_detail.cfm?ID=60

Comment: ^ Up-to-date link for Wyeast 3724 (Belgian Saison): https://www.wyeastlab.com/yeast-strain/belgian-saison

Answer (score 3):

If you can lay your hands on a [Kveik strain](http://www.theyeastbay.com/brewers-yeast-products/sigmunds-voss-kveik), you can make a Norwegian farmhouse ale. Kveik yeast ferments in temperatures up to even 40°C with comparatively little off aromas.

A Saison strain will feel alright in a slightly lower temperature spectrum, up to 30°C, maybe slightly over.

Answer (score 2):

You can brew a saission as suggested by other users, but with HotHead from Omega labs you can brew clean flavoured sytles up to far higher temps:

I advise looking at HotHead from Omega Labs: http://www.omegayeast.com/portfolio/14158-2/

- Flocculation: Medium-High
- Attenuation: 75-85%
- Temperature Range: 62-98° F (16-37° C)
- Alcohol Tolerance: 11% ABV

It is a really interesting yeast, for higher temp brewing and stops you having to only brew Saissions or Belgium styles in the hight of summer. I believe HotHead is Norwegian kveik strain.